# Sitecore 10.1 JSS Vue App zzz/myvueapp.config database web vs master on CD vs CM server

Tags: jss

In the `zzz/myvueapp.config` file should the database be set to `master on CM` and `web on CD`?

```
      <site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
        inherits="website"
        name="myjssapp"
        hostName="myhostname.com"
        rootPath="/sitecore/content/myjsstenant/myjsssite"
        startItem="/home"
        database="master" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No use web.
You also may use "web" on CM If you are in edit or preview mode Sitecore will use the master database. else it use the web database if that is configured in the site definition.

You can use master for development purpose, so then there is no publish needed to show latest content from master.